# Can android app access aidl-based hal service directly?

Tags: android, aidl, hal

I implemented a simple HAL service based on AIDL, which just makes communication with other android entity (some electronic control unit of automotive system). I need to access the service from some android app, but from what I searched from internet, it seems a system service is needed for app to access hal service, that is: "app <---> system service<--->hal service".

My question is: can the system service be skipped and make app access hal service directly via aidl interface? If not, is it only because of sepoliy or any other reason? thanks!